# How can I get the chapter number like a prefix of all references

Tags: cross-referencing

This was the problem I posted:
  "I need to output "see section 2.3" where the referenced section is the third on the second chapter."

You all are right. I've to redefine the problem.

Sections are referenced in a lot of distinct places:

- In table of contents. Managed by `\tableofcontents`
- In minitocs. Managed by `minitoc` package
- In headers. Managed by `fancyhdr` package
- Like a leader section. Managed by `\section`
- In text. Managed by `\ref`

In tocs and minitocs, because each section appears below its chapter (with some indentation) it's not necessary to prefix the section number with the chapter number. The label scope is local; so I need a local renderization. Example:

```
                  1. Chapter One ------------------1
                       1. First section -----------1
                       2. Second section ----------3
                   2. Chapter Two -----------------5
                       1. First section ...........5
```

This means that sections 1.1 and 2.1 must be rendered as section 1.

When we use the `\section` command we know what chapter we are in: it's shown in the headers of the page. So I want also local scope:

```
             1. First section
                       bla bla
             2. Second section
                       bla bla
```

In headers I want global scope:

```
             1. Chapter One                      1.1. First section
```

In text we can make a crossreference to whatever point of text. So we need global scope:

```
                See section 1.1 (first section in first chapter)
```

This is the problem:
The default behavoir give as global scope every where. But if I redefine `\thesection` to local scope, then I redefine everywhere.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[catalan]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex
\dominitoc

%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\thesection\ \ #1}}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\thechapter.\rightmark}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}

\minitoc[e]

\section{First section}\label{sec:A}

aaaaaa \newpage bbbbbbbb \newpage ccccccccccc

\chapter{Two}

\minitoc[e]

\section{Second section}\label{sec:B}

See sections \ref{sec:A} and  \ref{sec:B}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal working example, showing your document class and any _significant_ packages you load.

Comment: @meren: Actually (if I insert the document environment you forgot), the result is "See sections 1.1 and 2.1". Please verify that your examples compile and exhibit the behaviour.

Comment: That's true!!! But in my complete project this is not the behavoir. I'll try to find which package redefines the behavoir.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused by what you want. The point a name reference is that it is not the number: a real section is likely to have a descriptive name, and something like `section 1.1.Introduction` seems unlikely to be desirable.

Comment: So, what's your problem -- the fact that the ToCs use the prefixes too? Or just the fact that the header uses too many prefixes?

Comment: Also, btw, judging by the warnings `minitoc` outputs when imported before `hyperref`, you should probably import it afterwards instead...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you had the marks backward. You want the right mark on odd pages and the left mark on even pages.

So this is a bit of a hack, but it seems to work to get references to sections to appear how you want.

```
\documentclass[catalan]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\makeindex
\dominitoc

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thechapter.\thesection\ #1}}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\def\T@ref#1{%
        \NR@setref{#1}\checkforsectioni{#1}%
}
\def\checkforsectioni#1#2#3#4#5{%
        \checkforsectionii{#1}#4\@nil.\@nil\@nnil
}
\def\checkforsectionii#1#2.#3\@nil#4\@nnil{%
        \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{section}=\z@
                #3%
        \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{subsection}=\z@
                #3%
        \else
                #1%
        \fi\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document} \tableofcontents \chapter{One}

\minitoc[e]

\section{First section}
\label{sec:A}
aaaaaa \newpage bbbbbbbb \newpage
ccccccccccc

\chapter{Two} \minitoc[e]
\section{Second section}
\label{sec:B}

\subsection{Sub}
\label{sec:C}
See sections \ref{sec:A}, \ref{sec:B}, and \ref{sec:C}.

\end{document}
```

This works because hyperref writes entries in the aux file that look like

```
\newlabel{sec:A}{{1}{3}{First section\relax }{section.1.1}{}}
```

If you trace the execution of the `\ref`, you see that `\T@ref` expands to `\NR@setref{#1}\@firstoffive{#1}` and the `\@firstoffive` gets used before the second argument of `\newlabel`. That is, it eventually expands to

```
\@firstoffive{1}{3}{First section\relax }{section.1.1}{}
```

You can get a different behavior by replacing `\@firstoffive` with a 5 argument macro. In this case, `\checkforsectioni` which absorbs 5 arguments and then uses TeX's delimited argument capability to grab the text before the first period (if one exists) in its 4th argument. If that text is `section` or `subsection`, then the text that gets used is that after the first period, namely `1.1` in this case. Otherwise, it does the normal thing and expands to the first argument.

Comment: Wow!!!!!!!!!!! Very tricky. I don't understant how does it works, but it does!!!   Thanks a lot.

Comment: @meren: I added some explanation for why it works. If this solves your problem, you should accept it so it doesn't appear in the unanswered questions list.